# Create method to find webelement with xpath using JavaScriptExecuter

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, robotframework

I am trying to create a generic method to find the webelement with xpath as locator strategy using java script. Please help to complete the code , I have used the below code

```
path = //input[@id='image']  
def getElementByXpathJavaScript(driver ,path):
        return driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue")
```

When running the code i get the error

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: path is not defined
```

Basically I want to click on the element using java script executer . Do let me know if my approach is right ?

Answer (score 0):

The path variable should be passed as given below.

```
def getElementByXpathJavaScript(driver ,path):
        return driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate('"+path+"', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue")
```

Comment: But you can use directly the selenium api driver.find_element_by_xpath(), why do you want it in javascript?

Comment: I tired your code and i get the error WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: updated my answer. please check again. added quotes around the path.

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all :

```
WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: path is not defined
```

Which implies the `path` variable was not properly defined.

As you mentioned `Python` so you need to provide the `""` around the value of the `path` variable and the following code block should work the **`JavaScript`** way :

```
path = "//input[@id='image']"  
def getElementByXpathJavaScript(driver ,path):
    return driver.execute_script("return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue")
```

Incase you want to pursue the **`Python`** based **`JavaScriptExecutor`** way, which seems to be much simpler you can use the following option :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='image']")
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', element)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Basically I want to click on the element using java script executer

You can use robot's [assign id to element](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Assign%20Id%20To%20Element) to give an element a temporary id, and then you can use that id in your javascript. Since you're using the selenium library keyword to find the element, you can use any locator that you want.

For example:

```
assign id to element  xpath=//input[@id='image']  temporary_id
execute javascript    document.getElementById('temporary_id').click()
```